# Error with one to one in ODM [Symfony 2]

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I had this error msg while I'm making one to one relationship to display comments with some user info :

```
Warning: Warning: Illegal string offset '$id' in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\dev\doctrine\odm\mongodb\Hydrators\bulbizerFriendsBundleDocumentUsersInfoHydrator.php
```

So my commentClass is :

```
class Comments
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne( targetDocument="UsersInfo", mappedBy="userId" )
     */
    protected $userId;
....
}
```

and the usersinfo is :

```
class UsersInfo
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne( targetDocument="Comments", inversedBy="userId" )
     */
    public $userId;
...
}
```

Can someone explain me where is the problem ?

Comment: could you please provide the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\dev\doctrine\odm\mongodb\Hydrators\usBundleDocumentUsersInfoHydrator.php